# Strange occurrence in ExpressJS: Callback function isn't called

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, get

I'm using expressjs with node to create my web app but it's not working as supposed to.

Something really strange happens here, if I go to the first link in the browser, it works as supposed to but if I go to the second link it doesn't get executes the callback and returns `null`. And as you might see they're identical!

First API code Snippet (First Link):

```
/**
 * GET /workspace/friends/list
 * JSON friend list API
 */

app.get('/workspace/friends/list', passportConf.isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  var userFriends = [];
  //console.log(req);
  for (var i = 0; i < req.user.friends.length; i++) {
    if (req.user.friends[i].verified) {
      userFriends.push(req.user.friends[i]);
    }
  }
  res.json(userFriends);
});
```

Second API code Snippet (Second Link):

```
/**
 * GET /workspace/friends/sentRequests/
 * JSON friends requests list API
 */

//TODO: Fix API
app.get('/workspace/friends/sentRequests', passportConf.isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  var userFriends = [];
  //console.log(req);
  for (var i = 0; i < req.user.friends.length; i++) {
    if (!req.user.friends[i].verified) {
      userFriends.push(req.user.friends[i]);
    }
  }
  res.json(userFriends);
});
```

***Note:*** I must also add that if I uncomment the console.logs in both I get a log from the first but not the second one.

How is this even possible? Has anyone encountered something similar before? And how could I fix it?

Comment: @meagar yes it I'm getting a 200 state. :-/

Comment: For me it looks like you have a similar route defined somewhere else which fires and ends the request.

Comment: @Steffen Not the problem either, because I've searched the file for `'/workspace/friends/sentRequests'` and only got 2 matches, the one in the commentated block and in the get request. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. It's aparrently some sort of Bug that disables one to use long and/or Upper-Case characters in the link, [please see this issue I've created (issue #2256)](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/2256).

So when I changed it to the following, it worked fine:

```
/**
 * GET /workspace/friends/sentRequests/
 * JSON friends requests list API
 */

//TODO: Fix API
app.get('/workspace/friends/requests/sent', passportConf.isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  var userFriends = [];
  console.log(req);
  for (var i = 0; i < req.user.friends.length; i++) {
    if (!req.user.friends[i].verified) {
      userFriends.push(req.user.friends[i]);
    }
  }
  res.json(userFriends);
});
```

***Note:*** I haven't figured out where the bug originates.

***Update (22/07/2014):*** What happened is that the boilerplate [Skeleton](https://github.com/dstroot/skeleton) has defined Express's option for `case sensitive routing` enabled so when I was using and also uses the module [express-uncapitalize](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-uncapitalize) so when I defined the link with upper-case characters and put that exact same link in the browser it was uncapitalized and express couldn't find that link but uncpitalized (because it's case sensitive).

Comment: A stupid question, but are you sure it's working without `passportConf.isAuthenticated` middleware ? And are you sure this is function handling (req,res,next) parameters ? I don't know if it is related to your issues, but while playing with Passport.js, I made a silly mistake that drove me crazy for about a week. I was relying on the `req.isAuthenticated()` method Passport provides. But when I wrote my test, I forgot the parentheses, which resulted in my app only checking if `req.isAuthenticated` was defined...
But maybe this has nothing to do with your problem, sorry if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @WaldoJeffers but everything is working fine on other API GET listeners... It seems that the version of Express I'm using has a option to block uppercase characters in links and that's what happened, it's a definition used by the boilerplate I'm using ([Skeleton](https://github.com/dstroot/skeleton)), see [this issue](https://github.com/dstroot/skeleton/issues/25).